# How would I go about fixing SIM card not registering after flashing a custom ROM made for a clone of my device

Tags: hardware, rom, sim-card, 7.1-nougat

So, I have a BLU Life One X, which is a clone of the Micromax Canvas 5 and a few others.  I've installed a ROM made for the Canvas 5, after making a bunch of mistakes, including wiping *my entire system*.  The ROM is working just fine except for the actual phone part, which is not registering the SIM card.  WiFi works just fine.

### More details [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/-t3696730).

Cheers,

Neveraht, or whatever my name is on here.

Comment: More to your question, in general, ROMs are VERY specific to devices, one that is a "clone" or nearly the same often has enough differences that the ROM cannot be shared directly. In this case you said you wiped your entire system, does that mean the /system partition, or ALL partitions? If all, you likely wiped your IMEI number and if you do not have it or the tools to correct it, it may not be possible to fix this issue. I would try to go back to pure stock with the correct firmware and test before continuing.

Comment: I wiped the whole thing, not just the /system partition.  However, it's not registering the IMEI at all, and everything I've used to try and fix it haven't worked.

Comment: Please include all details of your question or issue in your question, having an external source is acceptable, but it should not be necessary to understand the issue. (updated original comment)

Comment: I would recommend restoring a stock, factory image for your device and see if you can get it working, otherwise the loss of IMEI may not be recoverable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:
Wiping Dalvik/ART Cache, Data, System, and Cache.
Flashing the ROM (Resurrection Remix).
Flashing the kernel fix.
Restoring Tee, NVData, and NVRam from my TWRP backup.

See [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/problems-sim-cards-registering-flashing-t3696730) for extra details.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The link probably shouldn't disappear - it's XDA - but I'll paste the main section for reference anyway.